# Actionmailer not working when I change gmail password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I have a Rails app that uses Gmail to send Actionmailer emails. It has been working great for months, but now that I changed my Gmail password it has stopped working and I get an error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I've adjusted the new password in my production.rb and development.rb files:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
#domain:               'thetens.us',
user_name:            'myaddress@gmail.com',
password:             'mypassword',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I'm sure the password is correct. Is there some way to force it to update wherever it's not being updated?

Comment: Have you restarted the server after changing the password in the above config file.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque yes, both locally and on heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named as **setup_mail.rb** in **config/initializers/** folder so that it looks like

```
config/initializers/setup_mail.rb
```

and put the below code in that file:-

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port  => 587,
  :domain  => 'www.yourdomain.com',
  :user_name => "myaddress@gmail.com",
  :password => "mypassword",
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "www.yourdomain.com"
```

Comment: why do you use ' and " ?