# Error setting up SMTP for Gmail for making a Contact Us Page using RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, contact-form

I am following [this tutorial](http://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password/) to setup a `Contact Us` form using Rails. I want the content on the form to be  mailed to my personal account. I followed the instructions as mentioned and when I run `foreman start`, I get the following error.

```
/home/adhithya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `“smtp' for #<PersonalWebsite::Application:0x9b6e4c4> (NoMethodError)
from /home/adhithya/Desktop/RailsDev/rocky-oasis-9687/config/environments/development.rb:37:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/adhithya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
```

I have not installed Devise though, as I do not need any authentication on my website because I do not have a login model.

I would like to know how to get this to work. Also, suggestions on the best way to implement a simple contact us form for a single page website using Rails would be helpful.

My development.rb looks like this

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: “smtp.gmail.com”,
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: “plain”,
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Comment: Please paste the development.rb file (around line 37)

Comment: I've just edited it. I have updated the post with my development.rb

Comment: I think you have problem in smtp setting. Try this

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459

Answer (score 0):

Basic and the simplest solution is:

```
#config/routes.rb
match "contact" => "welcome#contact", :as=> "contact", :via=>[:get,:post]


#controllers/welcome_controller.rb
def contact
   if(params[:name] && params[:message] && params[:email])
    NotificationsMailer.send_contact(params[:name] ,params[:email],params[:message]).deliver
    redirect_to root_path, notice: t('notice.welcome.contact')
  else
    render 'welcome/contact'
  end
end

#views/welcome/contact.html.haml
%form{:method => :post}
  %h2 Contact form
  %input{:type=>"hidden", :name=>"authenticity_token", :value=>form_authenticity_token.to_s}
  %div
    %label.control-label{:for=>"name"}
      Name
    %input{:name=>"name", :type=>"text", :required=>true, :maxlength => 50}
  %div
    %label{:for=>"email"}
      Email
    %input{:name=>"email", :type=>"email", :required=>true}

  %div
    %label.control-label{:for=>"message"}
      Message
    %textarea{:name=>"message", :id=>"message", :rows=>'5', :required=>true}

  %div.form-actions
    %input.button{:type=>"submit", :value=>"Send"}

#mailers/notifications_mailer.rb
def send_contact(name,email,message)
  @name=name
  @email = email
  @message = message
  mail(:subject=>"Message form contact form")
end
```

Comment: I would use a tableless model instead and a resource route personally

Comment: You have to change form(build form for resource) and action on submit(change params names)