# Rails: uninitialized constant Depot (NameError) while configuring mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I configured environment.rb file like this:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

rapp::Application.configure do
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address:        "smtp.gmail.com",
        port:           587,
        domain:         "gmail.com",
        authentication:     :login,         # will send password Base64 encoded
        user_name:      "myadress",
        password:       "mypass",
        enable_starttls_auto:   true
    }
end
```

But when I try to generate mailer class like this:

```
rails generate mailer MailNotifier template1 template2 template3
```

I got this error:

```
/home/usr/.../rapp/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `rapp' for main:Object (NameError)
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Could someone help to fix this?

Comment: Is that the name of your app?

Comment: I mean, is your application named `Depot`? Look in your `application.rb` file.

Comment: I changed the name to 'rapp' which is my application's name but still the same problem..

Comment: Your app's name is `rapp`, lower-case? Please stick with Ruby conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your action_mailer as:-

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459
```

Delete this from **environment.rb** file

```
rapp::Application.configure do
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address:        "smtp.gmail.com",
        port:           587,
        domain:         "gmail.com",
        authentication:     :login,         # will send password Base64 encoded
        user_name:      "myadress",
        password:       "mypass",
        enable_starttls_auto:   true
    }
end
```

Then try:-

```
rails generate mailer MailNotifier template1 template2 template3
```