# Rails mailer deliver : getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

When I'm trying to send a confirmation mail to users in my rails application, it puts me this error in my browser:

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

Highlighting this line: `SwarmNotifier.confirmvisitor(@member).deliver`

Here the swarm_notifier.rb in mailer:

```
class SwarmNotifier < ActionMailer::Base

  def confirmplayer(member)
    @member = member

    mail :to => @member.email, :from => "myappadress@gmail.com", :subject => "Player registration confirmation"
  end

  def confirmadmin(member)
    @member = member

    mail :to => @member.email, :from => "myappadress@gmail.com", :subject => "Administrator registration confirmation"
  end

  def confirmvisitor(member)
    @member = member

    mail :to => @member.email, :from => "myappadress@gmail.com", :subject => "Visitor registration confirmation"
  end
end
```

The member_controller.rb which call those confirmation methods is like:

```
 def create
    @member = Member.new(member_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.save
    case @member.role
    when "visitor"
          SwarmNotifier.confirmvisitor(@member).deliver
    when "administrator"
          SwarmNotifier.confirmadmin(@member).deliver
    when "player"
          SwarmNotifier.confirmplayer(@member).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @member }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My setup_mail.rb look like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "stmp.gmail.com", 
  :port  => 587,
  :domain  => 'localhost',
  :user_name => "myappadress@gmail.com",
  :password => "mypass",
  :authentication => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
```

Can someone help me fix this ?

Comment: Try changing your local host name as `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I just did it and I'm having the same error..

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459

Comment: The same error again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the magic solution: The firewall of my school blocked my smtp connection...

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error - You forgot `=>` after `:from`

```
mail :to => @member.email, :from => "myappadress@gmail.com", :subject => "Player registration confirmation"
```

Comment: Now that I fixed this I'm having another error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known at this line SwarmNotifier.confirmvisitor(@member).deliver in swarm_notifier.rb

Comment: you have not configured mail server in your localhost yet or your system does not have Internet connection.

Comment: I thought configuring setup_mail.rb were enough ? Should I install sendmail?

Comment: and how can I know if my application have access to internet connection?

Comment: that would be a separate question

Comment: In the console, It seems like the email is sent but nothing inbox: Sent mail to receiver@gmail.com (92.1ms)
Date: Sun, 11 May 2014 15:42:55 +0200
From: adressapp@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Message-ID: <536f7e5fc0222_77e7279e2ec223@user.mail>
Subject: Visitor registration confirmation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_536f7e5fb79be_77e7279e2ec132";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit