# Action mailer doesn't send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

whith this noitifier

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
default_url_options[:host] = "url"  

def deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)  
  @user = user
  @subject = 'Password reset instructions.'
  @sent_on = Time.now
  #default host is defined in development.rb configuration file
  @edit_password_reset_url = url_for :controller => 'password_reset', :action => 'edit'
  @edit_password_reset_url += "?id=#{user.perishable_token}"
  mail to: user.email
end  
end
```

and with this configuration on config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
:host => 'localhost',
:port => '3000'
}
# Options: :smtp, :test
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port => 587,
:domain => 'gmail.com',
:user_name => 'mymail',
:password => 'mypassword',
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

It doesn't send nothing ,what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Setup action mailer as in this post [Actionmailer not working when I change gmail password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459)

Edit notifier as:-

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "test@example.com"

 def deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)  
  @user = user
  @sent_on = Time.now
  #default host is defined in development.rb configuration file
  @edit_password_reset_url = url_for :controller => 'password_reset', :action => 'edit'
  @edit_password_reset_url += "?id=#{user.perishable_token}"
  mail to: user.email, :subject => "Password reset instructions."
 end  
end
```

In password_reset_controller:--

```
def create
 #send email as
 Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)
end
```

In **app/views/notifier/** create a page named as **deliver_password_reset_instructions.html.erb** and put the content which is sent in the mail.

Comment: i have setup action mailer in setup_mail.rb and have edited notifier but still doesn't work

Comment: have you checked in log that mail is sent or any error occurs ?

Comment: can you post the PasswordResetsController create method code.