# Mailer Setup - Basic Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailer

I setup the RoR4-Mailer a long time ago. It works fine. After a while I didn't get emails anymore. I can't remember how I setup it up, so I asked google. After resetup I get an Error as you can see at the bottom.

Can anybody tell me how I configurate it correctly ? (I only want to use the basics. No Devise or any other Gem.)

My Code-Snippets:

**/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb:**

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    user_name: ENV["MAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["MAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
}
```

**/config/environments/development.rb:**

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  #default host-url
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
      :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

**/local_env.yml:**

```
GMAIL_DOMAIN: 'gmail.com'
GMAIL_USERNAME: 'username@gmail.com'
GMAIL_PASSWORD: 'password'
```

**/config/application.rb:**

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

**error-exception:**

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in AuthController#send_pwd_reset_instructions
530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

Comment: setup mailer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459

Comment: Try logging in and determining if the account has been flagged for suspicious activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227532/gmail-530-5-5-1-authentication-required-learn-more-at

Comment: @ShamsulHaque:
If I don't use the ENV.Var it works fine. Thanks.
But I will ask google how to use the ENV.Var correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **ShamsulHaque**'s comment:
"setup mailer as stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/… –  Shamsul Haque yesterday"

Comment: you should vote up if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300150/actionmailer-not-working-when-i-change-gmail-password/23300459#23300459 helped you.